# I was doing a code for , "Count Digits " , Evenly divides means whether N is divisible by a digit i.e. leaves a remainder 0 when divided

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error, divide-by-zero, integer-arithmetic

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 

int main() {


int n,m,z;
   cout<<"enter n: ";
   cin>>n;
     z=n;

    int count=0;
while(n>0){
    m = n % 10;
    if(z%m == 0){
        count++;
    }
    n=n/10;
}
cout<<count;

}
```

Code should work like that ex - for n = 12, it is divisible by both 1 , 2 so, the output will be 2
if i am taking any value which have '0' in their last then it is not working ..and i am getting an error "Floating-point exception (SIGFPE)".
Could anyone help me to get rid out of this.

Comment: What happens if `m` is zero in `if (z % m == 0)`? You get a division by zero.

Comment: Make sure that `m` isn't zero, when you perform the modulo operation!

Comment: What reference or C++ course teaches to use `<bits/stdc++.h>`?  It's not a standard header.  You should change your habits to only include the headers that you need.

Comment: Ok...I will include only those which I need.....but what to do in place of m=n % 10 ..in easy wat

Answer (score 0):

This while loop

```
while(n>0){
    m = n % 10;
    if(z%m == 0){
        count++;
    }
    n=n/10;
}
```

does not make a great sense. For example `m` can be equal to `0` after this statement

```
    m = n % 10;
```

and as a result this statement

```
    if(z%m == 0){
```

produces a run-time error.

The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int count = 0;

    int n;

    std::cout << "enter n: ";

    if ( std::cin >> n )
    {
        const int Base = 10;

        int tmp = n;
    
        do
        {
            int digit = tmp % Base;
            if ( digit != 0 && n % digit == 0 ) ++count;
        } while ( tmp /= Base ); 
    }

    std::cout << "count = " << count << '\n';
}
```